# cannot find symbol PackageManager

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am trying to create a very simple code to open an application from another application.

The code used is as follows ,

```
android.app.Activity import;
android.content.Context import;
android.content.Intent import;
android.content.pm.PackageManager import;

public static void LaunchApplication()
{
GetPackageManager PackageManager = PackageManager();
startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("antay.cfsatv30localization"));
}
```

... but when I compile I get the following errors:
Error returned:

```
src\antay\startandstopapp\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_GlobalProcedures.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
getPackageManager();

^

symbol:   method getPackageManager()
location: class GWDCPCOL_GlobalProcedures
```

===================

```
src\antay\startandstopapp\wdgen\GWDCPCOL_GlobalProcedures.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("antay.cfsatv30localization"));

^

symbol:   method startActivity(Intent)
location: class GWDCPCOL_GlobalProcedures


2 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
GetPackageManager PackageManager = PackageManager();
```

with:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
```

What your first line declares is a new variable with the *name* 'PackageManager' of *type* 'GetPackageManager' where you try to assign the result of a non-existant function "PackageManager" to, whereas the type of the Android PackageManager is 'PackageManager' (no Get-prefix) and the Activity's public method to retrieve it, is called 'getPackageManager', just a case of unfortunate typos :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of problems, for instance:

- using GetPackageManager that is not a class name that you can have heard about.
- creating a variable with the exact same name of a class that you are using in the same context.
- creating an object without using new.

Besides, you are not following important naming conventions: you should never user a Capitalized name for functions or fields. Capitalized names are for classes in almost all languages. Why? because it look nicer, and because you avoid mistakes, like PackageManager = PackageManager(). Here you expect to use a class name and a var with the same. Also your LaunchApplication should be LaunchApplication.

I recomend you to read first some tutorials on OOP before you go on learning android, since it is clear that you are missing the basics, and you will have many problems.

for now, just change `GetPackageManager PackageManager = PackageManager();` to `PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();`

and also, i dont know if you just pasted it wrong, but the imports at the beginning of the file should be

```
 import android.app.Activity;
```

instead of

```
 android.app.Activity import;
```

and the same with all of them